# Captain becomes sleeping pod

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship, space, suspended-animation

What's the movie where they have upright hypersleep pods. The crew is strapped in and when they wake up they find that their captains harness slipped (I guess years back) because his face was pressed against the front of the pod and his flesh was growing onto the glass. I think he was still alive but they couldn't cut him free,

Comment: Can you add any more? What year was the movie made (approx), Can you remember any actors, other specific scenes? Was the movie in English or another language. Were the actors American etc.

Comment: Sounds kind of lame. Why would his flesh grow into glass, which is pretty non-porous, but not into the harness?

Comment: @chepner - His pod was ruptured and his body kinda fused with the materials he was touching, including the restraint and the glass.

Comment: @Valorum Ah, the "dimension jump" mentioned in the answer makes a better explanation than just prolonged physical contact.

Comment: @chepner: "Why would his flesh grow into glass" - well ... [weird things happen](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/1581630/Woman-stuck-after-two-years-on-toilet.html) ...

Answer (score 9):

This is *[Supernova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_(2000_film))* with James Spader, made in 2000.

[image: Movie Poster]

> Supernova chronicles the search and rescue patrol of a medical ship in deep space in the early 22nd century and its six-member crew, which includes captain and pilot A.J. Marley (Robert Forster), co-pilot Nick Vanzant (James Spader), medical officer Kaela Evers (Angela Bassett), medical technician Yerzy Penalosa (Lou Diamond Phillips), search and rescue paramedic Danika Lund (Robin Tunney) and computer technician Benjamin Sotomejor (Wilson Cruz). Aboard their vessel, the Nightingale 229, they receive an emergency distress signal coming from an ice mining operation on the moon Titan 37, more than 3,000 light years away.

[This review](http://www.screenit.com/movies/2000/supernova.html) mentions the face-glass bit:

> We see that Marley didn't make it that well through the dimension jump. As such, his body is somewhat deformed and part of his face is fused to the glass of his safety pod.

[image]

For the sake of completeness, the trailer: